# Get value of <select> element with React.useState in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am facing a problem in Nextjs with the useState function from React.

I have an  element, with several  in itself. Now, if I select e  useState should set a variable with the selected 's value.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

...

function logValue() {
  console.log(value)
}

return (
<div>
  <select onChange={(e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option selected value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
  </select>

  <button onClick={logValue}>submit</button>
</div>
)
```

My problem is now, that the first time I make a change in the select field, `setValue` sets the value from before the change.

When I load the page and change the selected to "a", `logValue` prints nothing.
Then I change the value to "d", `logValue` prints "a".
Then I change the value to "c", `logValue` prints "b". etc...

How can i make this work, that when I change the select field to "a" `logValue` prints "a"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check the console you should be able to see a `` Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option> ``

So you need to do something like that instead:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("b");

  function logValue() {
    console.log(value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
        <option value="d">d</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick={logValue}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This eliminated the error in the console, but now the select field sticks to the value from `value={value}` and it still doesn't set the new value on change...

Comment: How is that so? I've made Codesandbox example and it works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67202439-nsj9l

Comment: You are right!
I think I messed up my code very badly... There is a problem with my several `useState` i have in my code...